# JMeter- extract multiple variables from JSON response and save it in CSV file

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, post-processor, json-extract

I have seen several posts related to this, but I couldn't find a close match to my scenario, hence posting it as a new question.

I have a below JSON response

```
{
  "myshop": [
    { 
      "url": "test1",
      "hits": 1000
    },
    { 
      "url": "test2",
      "hits": 2000
    },
    { 
      "url": "test3",
      "hits": 3000
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to extract each of URL, its corresponding hits, and store it in a CSV file, in this case, it would be 3 lines in the CSV file

```
test1,1000
test2,2000
test3,3000
```

but couldn't succeed in doing this. My JSON extractor:

> $..url;$..hits with match number as -1

but it picks all the URLs but any random value of hits.
Also, I was able to use a for each controller with one variable to extract from JSON, write it to CSV using BeanShell post processor successfully but the same doesn't work for this case. Any pointers would be helpful.
I did check there were few answers with JSR223 Post processor but that did not cover this problem scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).myshop.each { entry ->
       new File('entries.csv') << entry.get('url') << ',' << entry.get('hits') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   }
   ```
3. That's it, once you run your test `entries.csv` file will be generated in JMeter's "bin" folder containing the information in the required format.

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

Also be aware that the approach will reliably work given the code is executed with maximum 1 thread at a time (i.e. make sure to use [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)). Otherwise consider switching to [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dmitri, worked like a charm. 

Is there a way to include one more variable extracted from the previous HTTP Get request to append to myshop.each entry ? 
Basically, the first Http Get request responds with an identifier, the second HTTP GET request mentioned here produces the response based on this identifier in fact it contains this identifier in the HTTP GET method

Comment: You can access JMeter Variabels using `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like `new File('entries.csv') << entry.get('url') << ',' << entry.get('hits') << ',' <<  vars.get('your_variable_from_previous_request') << System.getProperty('line.separator')` . More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)